# Finding Events on Slots in range

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I want to get number and position of slots that get occupied in a random process. The situation is like this:

There are total $50$ slots available ($1$ to $50$) at any given instant and there are total $20$ events (slots) getting occupied (any $20$ slots between $1$ to $50$). There would be slots that are not occupied at all since events are $20,$ less than $50,$ and also there would be some slots occupied by $1$ node and also possible to be occupied by more than $1$ node.

Now how can I get on average how many slots out of $20$ got occupied by $1$ node, $2$ nodes, $3$ nodes, $4$ nodes, etc. and also count of those slots that were not occupied by any node. For example this could be one of the scenarios where for $20$ events, slot no. $1$ occupied by **$4$ nodes** (**$4$ events covered**), slot no. $3$ occupied by **$2$ nodes**, slot no. $5$ by **$3$ nodes**, slot no. $10$ by **$3$ nodes**, slot no. $15$  occupied by **$3$ nodes** and slot no. $18$ by **$2$ nodes** and slot no $20$ by **$3$ nodes**. So, total $20$ events covered and slot no $2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17$ and $19$ (total $13$ slots) were not occupied by any node.

Comment: I would start small. I would start with the question: What is the probability that there are no slots that have two nodes? That then leads to a combinatorics question: How many ways are there to distribute the nodes so that there are no slots that have two nodes?

Comment: Hint: You might start by taking some $n$ with $1 \le n \le 20$ and see if you can find the probability that slot $1$ contains exactly $n$ events.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, If i get probability for each slot to have exactly n events where n is between 1 to 20, then would it not be same for each of the slots, i mean the probability outcome?, since for every slot we have to do same procedure.